# I can't create more than one virtual machine with vmbuilder

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, vmbuilder

I'm testing the creation of virtual machines with Ubuntu. The first virtual machine was created with the default settings and is called `ubuntu`:

```
virsh --connect qemu:///system list --all
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
 -     ubuntu                         shut off
```

I'm creating an additional virtual machine:

```
vmbuilder kvm ubuntu \
--suite saucy \
    --flavour virtual \
    --user demo \
    --pass demo \
    --arch amd64 \
    --dest /var/vm/demo1 \
    --part vmbuilder.partition \
    --domain demo1 \
    --ip 192.168.1.3 \
    --mask 255.255.255.0 \
    --gw 192.168.1.1 \
    --dns 192.168.1.2 \
    --libvirt qemu:///system \
    --addpkg linux-image-generic \
    --addpkg openssh-server
```

The command fails with the following error:

> Domain ubuntu already exists at qemu:///system

Why is it sticking with `ubuntu`? Isn't it the purpose of `--domain` to set the name of the domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error talks about a domain, but it's actually the host name which is already in use.

The `--domain` option sets the domain to which the VM belongs, not the actual name of the machine. To set the name of the machine, use `--hostname` option (found in `vmbuilder kvm ubuntu --help`).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. Each VM will have a subdirectory called ubuntu-kvm

I overcame this issue by creating a new directory for each VM.

you have to create e.g. /var/lib/libvirt/images/vm1, /var/lib/libvirt/images/vm2, and so on.

Each VM will have a subdirectory called ubuntu-kvm, and there can be just one such directory in /var/lib/libvirt/images/vm1.

If you try to create a second VM in /var/lib/libvirt/images/vm1, you will get an error message saying ubuntu-kvm already exists.